# Can I input a Byte Tensor to my RNN/LSTM model?

Tags: python, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I am developing an RNN/LSTM model to which I want to encode the sequence in a ByteTensor to save memory as I am limited to a very tight memory. However, when I do so, the model returns the following error:

> Expected object of scalar type Byte but got scalar type Float for argument #2 'mat2'

So, there seems to be something else that is need to be Byte tensor as well, but I do not know what is it since the console only shows an error at the line:

```
output = model(predictor)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that inside the `model` there are float tensors which are being used to operate on your byte tensor (most likely operands in matrix multiplications, additions, etc). I believe you can technically cast them to byte by executing `model.type(torch.uint8)`, but your approach will sooner or later fail anyway - since integers are discrete there is no way to used them in gradient calculations necessary for backpropagation. `uint8` values can be used in deep learning to improve performance and memory footprint of *inference* in a network which is already trained, but this is an advanced technique. For this task your best bet are the regular `float32`s. If your GPU supports it, you could also use `float16` aka `half`, though it introduces additional complexity and I wouldn't suggest it for beginners.

Comment: Could you please illustrate how can I proceed with using the `uint8` to improve performance. I have a critical case this is not just some exercise. Thank you.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's not currently supported by PyTorch out of the box though it is stated as a [goal](https://pytorch.org/blog/the-road-to-1_0/). The general term you want to look is "quantized inference" and there are resources on the topic such as [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.08342.pdf) whitepaper. The general problem you need to solve is how to accurately approximate 32bit fp arithmetic with 8bit integer arithmetic - quantize weights, replace normalization layers etc, all that without losing performance with respect to the trainable fp version.

Comment: Thank you very much. I believe these keywords you provided would help me a lot!